# C pointer to array of array of integers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What is the equivalent in C for inizializing a (constant) array of arrays of integers (of different dimensions) ?

In javascript it is like this:

> myarray=[ [1,2,3,4], [123,234], [1], [1,2] ]

```js
console.log(myarray=[ [1,2,3,4], [123,234], [1], [1,2] ])
```

How do I do the same in C?

Example:
This in C works:

```
const unsigned char *cf[] = { "\x2", "\x0,\x1,\x2", "\x3,\x4"};
```

I wish to do the same but without the quotes.

putting directly 2, [0,1,2], [3,4]

I explain better:

this works:

```
int c1[]={1,2,3,4};
int c2[]={5,6};
int c3[]={2,3,4}

int *arr[]={c1,c2,c3};
```

so I can access every element as `arr[0][x]`  `arr[1][x]`

now i have a big array.  how can I initialize it?

Comment: `struct Arr { int a[4]; int b[2]; int c[1]; int d[2]; } myarray={{1,2,3,4},{123,234},{1},{1,2}};`

Comment: isn't it possible without a struct?

Comment: I think the problem with your question is that it lacks any and all context. Neither why you need it, nor what you're trying to achieve, nothing. That would be a good reason for a downvote.

Comment: it is clear what I am trying to achieve... I am trying to translate what I just wrote in javascript... I even made the script in the question.

Comment: You cannot translate just what you wrote in JavaScript because the **exact** same thing is not possible in C. JavaScript has flexible data structures because it manages things “on the fly,” during execution. C requires rigid structures, defined at compile time. In order to produce code that accomplishes your purpose in JavaScript, one needs to know more about what you are doing with the data than is evident from just the snippet you showed, because that additional use of the data must be built into the data structure in C. And there are more differences that need more information to translate.

Comment: It can be done in several different ways, the real question is what you intend on doing with it. Based on that we can then tell you which approach you should use.

Comment: example: this works: const unsigned char *cf[] = { "\x2", "\x0,\x1,\x2", "\x3,\x4"};   I just wish to do the same but without using the quotes and only bytes

Comment: Okay but how are you going to input this array? Are you hardcoding it or reading it from some file/stdin?

Comment: True arrays in C have fixed size. If you want something with variable dimensions you have to use a table of pointers, each pointing at a chunk of data with a sentinel value.

Comment: As an example, in JavaScript, I believe you can refer to the subarrays with indices. In C, if they are defined as a structure like `struct Arr { int a[4]; int b[2]; int c[1]; int d[2]; }`, then you cannot refer to the subarrays with indices; you need to use their names. If you need to refer to them with indices in C, then another form of data structure must be used. This could be an array of pointers. But whether that is an appropriate option depends on what you want to do with the data, which is not shown in your snippet for defining it. So more information is needed to answer the question.

Comment: @qubit  hardcoding

Comment: What is wrong with *this works*?  It is a perfectly reasonable way to handle this.  I would probably generate the file from a script if it was that big or prone to change.

Answer (score 2):

```
const unsigned char *cf[] = { "\x2", "\x0,\x1,\x2", "\x3,\x4"};
```

> I wish to do the same but without the quotes.

---

Code could use *compound literals* to form the small `unsigned char` arrays. Yet `cf[]` (an array of pointers to `unsigned char`) loses knowledge of how big each array.

Not quite an "array of arrays of integers of different dimensions".

```
int foo() {
  const unsigned char *cf[] = {
      (unsigned char[]) { 2, ',', 0 }, 
      (unsigned char[]) { 0, ',', 1, ',', 2, 0 }, 
      (unsigned char[]) { 3, ',', 4, 0 }
  };
  return cf[0][0];
}
```

---

Note:
`"\x2"` is 2 bytes long.
`"\x0,\x1,\x2"` is 6 bytes long.
`"\x3,\x4"` is 4 bytes long.

`

Comment: I also thought about this.. I wonder if there is a cleaner way without casts.

Comment: @Zibri There are no _casts_ here, just definitions.

Answer (score 0):

*What is the equivalent in C...*

The short answer is there is nothing equivalent in C for doing what you are showing in `javascript`.

The most common way to do something *similar* in C is to use a struct:

```
typedef struct {
   int a[4];
   int b[2];
   int c[1];
   int d[2];
} ARR;

const ARR arr = {{1,2,3,4}, {123, 234}, {1}, {1,2}};
```

C99 (and beyond) implements *[flexible array members](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flexible-array-members-structure-c/)*.  This is similar, but again, not exactly what you want.  ( i.e. it also uses the `struct` construct.)

Comment: almost.. but the array is huge and elements have all different sizes... a struct won't cut it

Comment: @Zibri I hope you're not the downvoter, because adding a constraint like that in a comment on an answer means your question wasn't complete.  In that case I'd say it's the **question** that deserves the downvote.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I don't think Zibi down-voted. The down-vote came well after he commented.  This may have just been a competitive down-vote.  Thanks for jumping in though :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do it and it depends if you know exactly your input.

What I did was to store N + 1 size for the `int *nums` and then store the total length in the first memory position.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE_ARRAY 4

struct myArray{
  int *nums;  
};

int main()
{
    struct myArray myArrays[SIZE_ARRAY];
    myArrays[0].nums = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
    *(myArrays[0].nums) = 4;//the size of the allocated memory
    *(myArrays[0].nums + 1) = 1;
    *(myArrays[0].nums + 2) = 2;
    *(myArrays[0].nums + 3) = 3;
    *(myArrays[0].nums + 4) = 4;

    myArrays[1].nums = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    *(myArrays[1].nums) = 2;//the size of the allocated memory
    *(myArrays[1].nums + 1) = 123;
    *(myArrays[1].nums + 2) = 234;

    myArrays[2].nums = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    *(myArrays[2].nums) = 1;//the size of the allocated memory
    *(myArrays[2].nums + 1) = 1;

    myArrays[3].nums = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    *(myArrays[3].nums) = 2;//the size of the allocated memory
    *(myArrays[3].nums + 1) = 1;
    *(myArrays[3].nums + 2) = 2;

    printf("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_ARRAY; ++i)
    {
        printf("[");
        for (int j = 0; j < *(myArrays[i].nums); ++j)
        {
            printf("%d", *(myArrays[i].nums + j + 1));

            if (j < *(myArrays[i].nums) - 1)
            {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }

        printf("]");

        if (i < SIZE_ARRAY - 1)
        {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("]");

    return 0;
}
```

It gives the expected output but it's not as flexible as the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty in C is that there is no in-built data type that stores a heterogeneous list of elements. But of course, C being C, you can build something up yourself using pointers and structs, like my example below. The nasty implementation detail is that you need some way to store the size of each of your arrays, hence the need for a struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct container_t
{
  int size;
  int *item;
} container_t;

int main(void)
{  
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
  int b[] = {123,234};
  int c[] = {1};
  int d[] = {1,2};
  container_t s[] = {
                      {sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), a},
                      {sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]), b},
                      {sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]), c},
                      {sizeof(d)/sizeof(d[0]), d}
                    };

  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]); i++)
  {    
    printf("[");
    for(int j = 0; j < s[i].size; j++)
      printf("%d,", s[i].item[j]);
    printf("]\r\n");
  }
}
```

Output:

> [1,2,3,4,]
>
> [123,234,]
>
> [1,]
>
> [1,2,]

Comment: that's right.. but instead of a[] b[] c[]  I need an ARRAY a[0] a[1] etc etc

Comment: @Zibri Of course you can use an array as well. But you can't have an array of arrays of different sizes because you cannot have an array of dissimilar entities. You need to use an array of pointers and initialize the sizes correctly. Other things should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming syntax is the issue here (and not performance), you could try to create this from scratch.

In both cases the syntax is slightly more complicated than in your Javascript code. I'm not sure how much shorter one can make this in C, but you could probably make it a bit easier to read in C++.

Still, I provide 2 approaches below. Either by using variable arguments to handle the creation of smaller arrays or by parsing an array of strings, which is arguably even easier to read, but probably a bit slower.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

// I don't know what type you had in mind...
typedef int type_t;
#define type_t_specifier "%d"

typedef struct tab { // Helper struct
    type_t* data;
    size_t size;
} tab;

tab ctb(size_t size, ...) { // Parse one of the subarrays into the temporary struct
    tab res;
    res.size = size;
    res.data = (type_t*)malloc(res.size * sizeof(type_t));
    va_list valist;
    va_start(valist, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        res.data[i] = va_arg(valist, int);
    }
    return res;
}

typedef struct array_t { // Array struct
    type_t** data;
    size_t* sizes;
} array_t;

array_t create_array1(size_t size, ...) { // Create the array using variable arguments
    array_t array;
    array.data = (type_t**)malloc(size * sizeof(type_t*));
    array.sizes = (size_t*)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(size_t));
    array.sizes[0] = size;
    va_list valist;
    va_start(valist, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tab temp = va_arg(valist, tab);
        array.data[i] = (type_t*)malloc(temp.size * sizeof(type_t));
        array.sizes[i + 1] = temp.size;
        array.data[i] = temp.data;
    }
    return array;
}

array_t create_array2(size_t size, const unsigned char** temp) { // Or you can simply parse an array of strings instead
    array_t array;
    array.data = (type_t**)malloc(size * sizeof(type_t*));
    array.sizes = (size_t*)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(size_t));
    array.sizes[0] = size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int nsize = 1;
        for (int j = 0; temp[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (temp[i][j] == ',') {
                nsize++;
            }
        }
        array.data[i] = (type_t*)malloc(nsize * sizeof(type_t));
        array.sizes[i + 1] = nsize;
        int start = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= strlen(temp[i]); j++) {
            if (temp[i][j] == ',' || temp[i][j] == '\0') {
                sscanf(&(temp[i][start]), type_t_specifier, &array.data[i][cnt++]);
                start = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}

void delete_array(array_t array) { // Clean up the array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.sizes[0]; i++) {
        free(array.data[i]);
    }
    free(array.data);
    free(array.sizes);
}

void print_array(array_t array) { // Just to check if it works
    for (int i = 0; i < array.sizes[0]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.sizes[i + 1]; j++) {
            fprintf(stderr, type_t_specifier, array.data[i][j]);
            if (j != array.sizes[i + 1] - 1) fprintf(stderr, " ");
            else fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    array_t myarray;
    // You can either complicate the syntax a tiny bit by providing the lengths of each of the subarrays
    myarray = create_array1(4, ctb(4, 1, 2, 3, 4), ctb(2, 123, 234), ctb(1, 1), ctb(2, 1, 2));
    print_array(myarray);
    delete_array(myarray);
    // Or parse an array of strings to create your array
    const unsigned char* temp[] = { "1,2,3,4", "123,234", "1", "1,2" };
    myarray = create_array2(4, temp);
    print_array(myarray);
    delete_array(myarray);
    return 0;
}
// We need to parse the size of the outer array in both cases.
```

One way this could be improved for performance would also be to store the memory contiguously. This would make later use faster but probably cost a bit more time when constructing the array.

Or if you wanted to make it even easier to work with you could simply parse your original javascript array. Though I really would avoid parsing strings if possible.